# Writing a backbone.js view method that automatically scrolls down a DOM element with CSS overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

As the question asks. Writing a backbone.js view method that automatically scrolls down a DOM element with CSS overflow.

Say we've created a overflow div with the id="overflowdiv"

```
<div id="overflowdiv"></div>
```

and it is filled from a template with

messages. I am aware of how models, collections and views connect somewhat.

Either way, you can create custom functions for views using backbone. Is there a way to use such a function to target the "overflowdiv" element so that it updates every time a fetch or any sort of update event fires that affects "overflowdiv".

**If required I can provide further data to facilitate an easier awnser.**

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
$('#overflowdiv').children().last().get(0).scrollIntoView()
```

Put that in a method and call it after the container updates. See [`Element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: It certainly does something, slowly reducing the size of my chat window! other than that, it fails to accomplish much else.

Comment: @Hangfish This is psuedocode, exact code depends on your DOM structure which you haven't shared.  Basically you should to access the last chat message and invoke `scrollIntoView`. It'll work assuming you have sane CSS